# Highchart: different units per Y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do i add a unit for my individual Y axis?
I have 4 axis, all with different units (C, hPa, %)

My tooltip is currently like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
    return ''+
    Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.x) +': '+ this.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would like to add symbols in condition of serie? How you would like to recognise which symbol shoudl be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the tooltip according to series.

Example

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        if(this.series.name === 'Temperature') {
            return ''+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.x) +': '+ this.y + 'C';
        } else {
            return ''+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.x) +': '+ this.y + '%';
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pr8mn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add symbol in the end of line Highcharts.dateFormat() like

```
tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
return ''+
Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M',this.x) +': '+ this.y+' hPa';
}
```

}